# Vectorizing LIst of Unique Words into 0 or 1 using Python

Tags: python, vectorization, text-processing, cosine-similarity

I am quite new into Python, and recently have to do on some text processing to do a cosine similarity between two text.

I have currently be able to do on the basic pre-processing on the text such as lowercase them, tokenizing the text, removing stopwords, and stemming of those words by using the NLTK library. And now, I have able to create a list of unique words from all the text files that I got.

Then now, in this list of unique words that I have created, there are only certain words that I would like to vectorize it to 1 (and the rest to 0) according to a textfile that I have.

So for example, after vectorized the list of unique words, it should look something like below:

```
awesome| best | carry | elephant | fly | home | irresponsible | implicit 
1      | 1    | 0     | 0        | 0   | 1    | 0             | 0
```

I have tried googling and look through stack overflow here, but it seems one of the the common solution is using the scikit learn - features extraction in converting the list. However, I only wants either 0 or 1... and that the 1 should be specified by a textfile.

For example, there is one textfile (after vectorizing it all into 1) that I would like to compute the similarity with this dictionary... So it should look something like this below:

Text_to_Compare.txt

```
awesome | fly | implicit
1       | 1   | 1
```

And then, I will compare the "Text_to_Compare.txt" with the list of unique words and compute the similarity result.

Could anyone kindly guide me on how do I go on vectorize the list of unique words to only 0 or 1, and vectorzing the "Text_to_Compare.txt" to all 1?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're expecting the output to be? i.e. "I want to parse the text file into a Python dict like this: `{'awesome': 1, 'best': 1, 'carry': 0, ...}`". Right now it's difficult to tell what it is that you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @HenryKeiter, thanks for the prompt reply! The first thing I would like to do is to vectorize the list of words to 0 or 1. And then to compute the similarity between two files. So the final output should be something like 0.74 (depending on the similarity). But currently, I am still stuck at the vectorizing of the list of unique words...

Comment: You misunderstand. What do you expect the result of your *vectorizing* to be? From some of your text it sounds like you might just be looking for some data structure or output formatting advice, but "vectorize the list of words to 0 or 1" isn't a clear enough problem statement to be sure.

Comment: After I have vectorized on the unique words and the text file, the next I want to do is to compute on the similarity between those text files. Yes, you're right... I am not very sure how the output formatting should be like though I roughly know what I want to do (to eventually compute similarity between the unique words and the text file). Sorry for not getting the problem statement clear in the first place. I will be very appreciate if you could advice on the output formatting! Meanwhile, I shall try on the dictionary way that @BeeSmear have provided as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you wanted to do?

```
text_file = ['hello','world','testing']
term_dict = {'some':0, 'word':0, 'world':0}

for word in text_file:
    if word in term_dict:
        term_dict[word] = 1
```

If you've tokenized your file (`.split()` method in Python), then they will be available in a list.  Assuming that you've normalized each term (lowered, stemmed, stripped of punctuation, etc.) in your dictionary and your text_file, then the above code should work.  Just set all the values in your dict to 0, and loop your file, checking to see if the word is `in` the `dict`.  If it is, then set that value to 1.

Here is how you can generate a dictionary with values set to 0:

```
new_dict = {word:0 for word in text_file}
```

It's a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/).  Note again that my code assumes that you're normalizing all the terms -- comparing apples to apples -- and that's always key when working with text.

Final Edit.  If you have two lists of unique terms (after tokenizing and normalizing)

```
def normalize(term):
    #do stuff -- i.e., lower; stem; strip punctuation; etc.
    pass
word_list_one = [normalize(word) for word in text_doc.split()]
word_list_two = [normalize(word) for word in other_text_doc.split()]

# if you know the longest of your lists, then you can create a dictionary of ones and zeros from the two lists.
word_dict = dict([(word,1) if word in word_list_one else (word,0) for word in word_list_two])
# that's it.  in the above code, word_list_two should be the longer of your two lists (assuming I understand your code properly)
# Note: someone with more python experience could definitely improve my code.  I just wanted show you another option.
```

Please let me know if this works for you.  Hope it helps a little!

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I think what I wrote have caused some misunderstanding. The dictionary that I am referring is actually not the Python dictionary. It is like another list of unique words that I referred it as dictionary (I used this word because in information retrieval it means a set of unique words), shall edit my question to make it clearer (sorry about it). Actually what I want is to vectorize the list of words to 0 or 1 (actually is kind of similar to what you have provided), and then, i will be able to use the vectorized unique words and compare with another text file.

Comment: @Yoshiaki updated answer to create a dictionary from a list of words, setting all values to zero.

Comment: you sure have helped me out! Am grateful for the codes that you have provided. Now what's left for me is to compute the similarity between the dictionaries, which I will try it out myself first. Thanks once again!

Comment: @Yoshiaki Awesome!  Really happy I could offer some help.